# Calculate Prior Season Sales of Related Orders for a Given Opportunity

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, opportunity

I am trying to calculate 'Prior Season Sales' for a given Opportunity.

As an overview- We have a field called 'Season Sales' on the Opportunity object that is summing a field called 'Order Amount' on the Order object (Unit Price * Quantity) of all related Orders. Each Opportunity is categorized with a picklist field called 'Selling Season' with values such as Winter 2022, Spring 2022, Fall 2022... etc. My goal is to take the 'Season Sales' field on each Opportunity, and create a new field called 'Prior Season Sales' to display on each Opportunity that shows the prior season's 'Selling Season' value.

I have tried using a formula field but cannot tell which Opportunities are 'prior'. They are typically all related to an Account (one account has multiple seasons of Opportunities) but how can I achieve this?

Comment: Which do you mean by can not tell which opportunity is prior?

Comment: If Account A has 7 Opportunities, each with its own season, how can I update the 'Prior Season Sales' field on each of the Opportunities? Would this require a formula field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  to achieve this with record triggered flow.
With flow you can update  prior value into new field value.

Take the reference from these links [Refer to the Prior Values of the Record That Triggered Your Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_prior_values_flow.htm&type=5&release=230)

[Reference Prior Value in a Before/After Update Record Triggered Flows](https://jenwlee.com/2021/01/11/referencing-prior-value-in-a-before-after-update-record-triggered-flows/)